# Gas line replacement

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas, gasleak

Attached is picture of the gas line (and meter) which is at the bottom of the building, my condo is on 3rd floor.

There is a gas leak somewhere in the line, behind walls and ceiling. Leak is not inside my unit but somewhere within walls, before pipeline comes out in my unit.

1. What is the usual fix for this kind of problem? I know that line has to be replaced or joint has to be tightened, but how do they go about find the location of the leak ?
2. How much of the wall or ceiling they have to cut ?
3. do they replace it with similar metal pipeline or use flexible gas line ? I guess flexible line would be easy to install.

I am just worried about the cost here.

[image]

Comment: It is the owners problem not yours.  If there is a gas leak phone your local fire department and gas company.  After you can watch youtube for exploding buildings if you last that long.

Comment: crisp659- I am the owner, gas line has been disconnected already you can see in the picture, they installed meter to test pressure. No gas in the line right now, service is off.

Comment: The cost(which is not consider on this site) will depend on how close they can find the leak.  If in the walls can consider quite a bit of wall/ceiling removal along the gas lines to find the leak/s.  A known gas leak and insurance will not be paid if building goes boom/people die.  People will probably not stay happy without gas, so cheapest option is to get it fixed.

Comment: How did you become aware of the leak?  Odor, high gas usage, or other indication?  If there was odor, that might help narrow down a general area where the leak was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the usual fix for this kind of problem? I know that line has to be replaced or joint has to be tightened, but how do they go about find the location of the leak?

Usually it involves hacking into the wall and checking joints. The problem is almost always at a joint. I have had (as did many of my neighbors 20 - 30 years ago) pinhole leaks in copper *water* pipes. I have never heard of leaks in gas *pipes*, only in joints.

> How much of the wall or ceiling they have to cut?

That depends on how quickly they find the problem and how many joints there are and how accessible they are.

> Do they replace it with similar metal pipeline or use flexible gas line? I guess flexible line would be easy to install.

It looks like there are two different (maybe more than two...) types of "flexible" line. One is the type normally used for the last section connecting to an appliance. That type can't be inside walls. There is another type (CSST) which apparently can be used in place of the traditional black pipe. However, some jurisdictions and utilities restrict its use, and an earlier version of CSST was found to have some serious problems. In addition, the expected lifetime is 30 years compared to 75 years for traditional gas pipe. However, it does have the advantage of fewer joints, and since joints are where you get leaks, that can be a big plus.

Comment: Just of of curiosity, are yellow polyethylene (PE) gas lines allowed within walls, or do they have to be iron? I think in my house, it's yellow PE behind the kitchen walls. If so, maybe this is what the OP means by 'flexible'.

Comment: @Cheery Here's what one manufacturer of yellow PE pipe says: "Underground only. It may never be used in a building or under a foundation with a structure on it. Always outside, underground, at or below code-mandated burial levels."

Comment: CSST has special grounding requirements, as arcs can puncture its thin walls and cause a leak.